# Reading the copied decimal value from excel

Tags: c#, excel-2007, copy-paste

I am copying a value 8.03 from excel sheet and reading that value in C# from the clipboard using the code below. The value that is coming out is 8.0299999999999994 and not 8.03. When I look at the xml as in below the value is 8.0299999999999994. The sheet1.xml which is in the zip file of xlsx also has the value 8.02999999999999994. But when I copy the value to notepad the value gets copied at 8.03. What can I do to copy the value as 8.03 like in notepad?

```
DataObject retrievedData =  Clipboard.GetDataObject() as DataObject;
    if (retrievedData.GetDataPresent("XML Spreadsheet"))
    {
        var sourceDataReader = new XmlTextReader(retrievedData.GetData("XML Spreadsheet") as System.IO.Stream);
         var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
         var excelWorksheeet = doc.Element("Worksheet");
         XNamespace ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet";
         XName worksheetName = ns + "Worksheet";
         var worksheetElement = doc.Root.Element(worksheetName);
    }
```

The worksheetElement has the value:

```
 <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
   <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
     <Row>
       <Cell>
         <Data ss:Type="Number">8.0299999999999994</Data> 
       </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
```

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipboard has support for several formats. Obviously the `XML Spreadsheet` format does a different rounding of the underlying float value than excel does. If you want to get the data exactly as notepad does, try to get the `text` representation instead.

Of course, copying as `text` will not get all the detailed information that `XML Spreadsheet` gives you, but it all depends on what you want to do with the data.

An alternative is to get both representations. Get the `XML Spreadsheet` format to get the detailed data and use the `text` format to get a display string.